# Iterating through Excel sheets using ArcMap ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, excel

I am trying to use ModelBuilder(ArcMap 10.1) to add XY data to ArcMap, then export the events as Feature Classes. The data comes in one xlsx document with a large number of sheets, each with an X and Y column. So in the end I would have a set of point feature classes.

So far I haven't been successful in automating this procedure with ModelBuilder. My idea was to use the "Iterate Tables" tool and choose the xlsx document as input workspace; then continue with "Make XY Event Layer" and finally "FC to FC". In order to not overwrite previous results, I have added "%i%" to the output name. To be more precise, the model does run through the first sheet; the second run fails because the model tries to overwrite the first result (despite the %i% appendix). Using "%n%" instead, I get an infinite number of results all using the first sheet.

I suspect that either it is not possible to iterate through the sheets of an Excel table, or else maybe something is wrong with my naming system.

Comment: Not sure if it is an issue any longer, but previous versions of ArcGIS could make funny things out of .xlsx files. Might help saving it as a .xls instead.

Comment: Further to Martins idea you could import your worksheets into an Access database and that becomes the workspace for your iterate tables?

Comment: Python might be better for this case, as it will handle it better.

Comment: I would rather be trying to do this at 10.2 with Excel Toolset than at 10.1 - is that an option for you?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas. Saving the file as .xls did not change anything; I have not tried the Access approach yet. We will probably move to 10.2 soon, so maybe I'll have better luck there. Python will probably do this easily, however I was somehow hoping this might be a good example to demonstrate how iterations work in modelbuilder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if iterating Excel sheets is still an issue for you....

...but I was able to use Iterate Tables to successfully make an XY event layer and export to a feature class for all sheets in the original .xlxs document.  The tricky part for me was to remove the "$" from the sheet name because it was causing errors in the exporting (invalid character for feature class name).  I used the model only tool [Calculate Value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000v8000000) to edit the **%Name%** string of the current sheet.  Check the model labels for the expression.

I am sure there are ways to improve this model...but it does export a feature class for each excel sheet using the X and Y coordinate of the source table.  Enjoy.

[image: Iterate Excel Sheet model]

[View full size model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhb4I.png)

Comment: I added the "Calculate Value" tool to my model and it works fine. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

[image]Hi Guys,
I faced the same issue and I solved pretty much in the same way (hours lost finding out how to get rid of the $ as well!!). I used a wild card (Iterate Table > Make Var > from Par > Wildcard) to selct correct Excel sheets within the table. Sometimes it can be useful.
Cheers,
Marco